# How implement fail-over database in Java?

Tags: java, database, osgi-bundle

I have an OSGI bundle that connects to a database(it can be any vendor)  and collects the result by running a pre-defined query. Now I want to have a mechanism which supports connection to a secondary/failover database in case the primary databases is down or not accessible for any reasons.

How I'm handling it is:

```
try{
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                       primaryDbUrl,
                       primaryDbUsername,
                       primaryDbPassword
                    );
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                        secondaryDbUrl,
                        secondaryDbUsername,
                        secondaryDbPassword
                   );
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        }
```

This solution works fine so far. I want to know two things here:

1. Is there a better way to handle it?
2. Are there any scenarios where above code will fail?

Comment: What if first database goes down after you get the connection ? You may need to expand the boundary of try catch to include last statement you are going to fire. Btw, this shouldn't be handled at application level. Each database have their own way to switch over to backup.

Answer (score 0):

You can factor the code into a loop; if both these calls fail you can retry on an exponential back off.

Ideally I would put both databases behind a load balancer so they look as one to me

Comment: thanks for helping out. Putting both databases behind a load balancer is not an option for me as these databases belong to third-party. Could you please elaborate your first solution?